# Javascript objects & methods: what can see what, and why?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, closures

I've got a set up that, in stylised form, is like this:

```
(function () {
    var db = {
        com: {                    EDIT: Changed this from [...] to {...}
            324: {
                unmod: "xyz"
            }
        }
    };

    var report = {
        mymethod: function () {
            var x = db.com[324].unmod;
        }
    };
})();
```

The error message I'm getting is `db.com is undefined`. It seems to me that `report.mymethod` cannot "see" `db.com`.  Would that be right?

One factor might be that `db.com` is created by looping through AJAX data like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            cat = o.cat[i];
            length2 = cat.com.length;

            // Loop through comments
            for (j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                com = cat.com[j];

                // Create db object
                this[com.cnum] = {
                    unmod: com.unmod
                };
            }               
    }
```

Is the issue one of closure?

The relevant part of the AJAX data is like this

```
       "cat":[  
        { ...
          "com": [ {"cnum":"324", "unmod":"xyz"},...]  
        }, ...],
```

Apologies that the AJAX names and property names are the same. It makes it easier for me, but perhaps not for y'all :)

Comment: Your "stylised form" example is invalid Javascript, so is untestable. Without knowing how the code that populates `db.com` relates to the code that produces the error, nobody can guess what goes wrong.

Comment: @lanzz  Thanks for this. Which bit is invalid (and how)? The bit that populates `db.com` or the bit that attempts to access its contents?

Comment: The populate code. You cannot initialize array elements with the same syntax as object-literal (i.e., `[ 324: { ...` is a syntax error). With the error in the population fixed, your access code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/4bL8T/

Comment: @lanzz  Thanks for the jsfiddle.  It all works if I (1) add a property to db `com: {}` and then (2) change my populate loop to: `this.com[com.cnum] = {unmod: com.unmod};`  I changed my mind how I was going to do this, and forgot I'd inserted the `com` object. Put something in as an answer and I'll tick & +1 it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code works as expected after fixing the population part: http://jsfiddle.net/4bL8T/

Answer (score -1):

Before exec this code:

```
(function () {
var db = {
    com: [
        324: {
            unmod: "xyz"
        }
    ]
};

var report = {
    method: function () {
        var x = db.com[324].unmod;
    }
};})();
```

Check scope by console.log for `db.com` object, if the object undefined you need define it before use it.

Comment: It is obvious that `db.com` is defined inside the example, so it is in-scope.

Comment: Ok, if they defined, but when exec it they undefined. `db.com` is global variable? Maybe when we try to use `db.com` object we use not global variable. Or we stay at other scope layer.